# How to auto populate HTML fields by from Spreadsheet Data using Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to populate my form fields using Spreadsheet data using Phone number. If the user entered their phone number, fields will be auto populated (Name, email, etc)

Now, its only populating the Full Name.

My Code.GS:

```
function autoComplete(info){
  var opensheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0";
  var sso = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(opensheet);
  var wst = sso.getSheetByName("Invoices");

  var data = wst.getRange(2, 1, wst.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues();

  var phoneSearch = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var newsletter = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  var fullname = data.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });
  var email = data.map(function(r){ return r[4]; });

  var position = phoneSearch.indexOf(info);

  if(position > -1){
    return fullname[position];
  } else {
  return '';
  }
}
```

My Javascript:

```
 function getDetails(){

       var info = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;

       if(info.length === 14) {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateInfo).autoComplete(info)

       }

       }

        function updateInfo(fullname){
         document.getElementById("full_name").value = fullname;
       M.updateTextFields();

        }
```

I want to autocomplete the fields based on spreadsheet data. If user enters the phone number, the fields must be auto-filled up.

See screenshot: https://ibb.co/wJjz205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might extend your script to return additional values in the object, like:

```
    ...
    if(position > -1){
        return {
          'fullname': fullname[position],
          'email': email[position]
          // add other fields if necessary
          }
      } else {
      return '';
      }
      ...
```

and then access the vaules as the properties of returned object:

```
function updateInfo(response){
         document.getElementById("full_name").value =response['fullname'];
         document.getElementById("email").value =response['email'];

       M.updateTextFields();

        }
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! However, my select dropdowns doesnt change. What do I need to add?

Comment: can't advise on this. supposedly you'll have to update some `option` elements `innerText`, something like: `document.getElementById("email").innerText = response['email'];`

Comment: Is it possible to insert response['email']; to <option>?